# C code does not work when coded like C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Hello Developers! I am learning algorithms from Algorithms Design Manual Book by Skiena. There I have the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int item_type;

typedef struct{
    item_type item;
    struct list* next;
    }list;

void insert_list(list **l, item_type x){
    list *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
    }

int main(){
    return 0;
    }
```

It gives me Warning when compiled:

> gcc -Wall -o "test" "test.c" (in directory:
>   /home/akacoder/Desktop/Algorithm_Design_Manual/chapter2) test.c: In
>   function ‘insert_list’: test.c:15: warning: assignment from
>   incompatible pointer type Compilation finished successfully.

But when I rewrite this code as C++:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

typedef int item_type;

typedef struct{
    item_type item;
    struct list* next;
    }list;

void insert_list(list **l, item_type x){
    list *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l;
    *l = p;
    }

int main(){
    return 0;
    }
```

It gives the following:

> g++ -Wall -o "chapter2" "chapter2.cpp" (in directory:
>   /home/akacoder/Desktop/Algorithm_Design_Manual/chapter2)
>   chapter2.cpp:15: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct list
>   list’ chapter2.cpp:14: error: ‘struct list’ has a previous declaration
>   as ‘struct list’ chapter2.cpp: In function ‘void insert_list(list**,
>   item_type)’: chapter2.cpp: In function ‘void insert_list(list**,
>   item_type)’: chapter2.cpp:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’
>   to ‘list*’

Can anyone explain why it is so? And How can I rewrite it in C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem in both cases is in the struct definition: `struct list *next` doesn't refer to the struct you are in the process of declaring. Try this instead:

```
typedef struct list {
    item_type item;
    struct list* next;
} list;
```

In addition, in C++ you must cast the `void *` returned by `malloc` to the appropriate pointer type (`list *`), C++ is stricter about these things. Also, BTW, in C++ you can leave off the typedef completely if you want.

The reason for the differing error messages is a difference in the languages.

In C, the compiler knows that `struct list *` is a pointer to a struct, so it doesn't need to complain that it doesn't actually know what a "struct list" is yet. Later, though, when you try to assign this "struct list *" from a pointer of type "list *" (the type of which is "pointer to an anonymous struct"), it complains about the mismatch.

In C++, a "struct" declaration is more or less equivalent to a "class" declaration (the major difference is in the default visibility of members). Among other things, this means that structs in C++ are more or less automatically typedefed. So when the compiler sees "struct list *next", it takes it as a forward declaration of a class named "list"; then when it finishes the statement and processes the typedef, throws an error because you're trying to typedef something to an identifier that is already (forward-)declared as something else. Then it issues further errors because it doesn't actually know what "list" might be, due to the earlier error.

Comment: it doesn't have to have previous declaration, it interprets `struct list *next` as forward declaration.

Answer (score 9):

This is because c++ is stricter than c with respect to type conversions.

There are host of other errors in your code. Please note that just putting a c source code, renaming the file as `.cpp` & compiling using `g++` does not make a c source code as c++.

If you are writing a program in `c++` please use `new` & not `malloc`, doing so you do not need to explicitly type cast as in case of `malloc`.

Comment: This answer needs to be more specific: "There are host of other errors in your code" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Chris Johnson: By the time i finished writing the main erroneous part, other answers already came up with the `elaborated list` of errors, I don't think its worthwhile to repeat the same here, the answer, answered the basic flaw & the point I wanted to make.

Answer (score 6):

C++ does not allow arbitrary pointer conversions, while C does. But since this is not considered good style, the compiler emits a warning.

Just add a cast and it will solve both messages:

```
p = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

Or if you want to be C++ only:

```
p = new list;
```

But then, you should declare constructors and such, also.

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc()` is considered *poor* style in C.  It can mask errors; for example, if you forget the `#include <stdlib.h>`, some compilers will assume that `malloc()` returns an int.  An idiom that avoids type mismatches is: `p = malloc(sizeof *p);`.

Comment: And if you're trying to write code that will compile either as C or as C++, you're probably doing it wrong.  C/C++ interoperability is good enough that there's rarely a good reason to do this.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-vs-c++.html).

Quote:

> ***Gotcha for a C++ programmer using C***
>
> **Structs and Enums**
>
> You have to
>   include the struct keyword before the name of the struct type to
>   declare a struct: In C++, you could do this
>
> `struct a_struct {`
>       `int x; };`
>
> `a_struct struct_instance;`
>
> and have a new instance of `a_struct` called `struct_instance`. In C,
>   however, we have to include the `struct` keyword when declaring
>   `struct_instance`:
>
> `struct a_struct struct_instance;`
>
> In fact, a similar situation also holds for declaring enums: in C, you
>   must include the keyword `enum`; in C++, you don't have to. As a side
>   note, most C programmers get around this issue by using typedefs:
>
> typedef struct struct_name {
>          /* variables */ } struct_name_t;
>
> Now you can declare a `struct` with
>
> `struct_name_t struct_name_t_instance;`
>
> But there is another gotcha for C++ programmers: you must still use
>   the "`struct struct_name`" syntax to declare a `struct` member that is
>   a pointer to the `struct`.
>
> ```
> typedef struct struct_name {
>     struct struct_name instance;
>     struct_name_t instance2; /* invalid!  The typedef isn't defined
> yet */ } struct_name_t;
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this class:

```
typedef struct{
    item_type item;
    struct list* next;
    }list;
```

to this:

```
struct list {
    item_type item;
    list* next;
    };
```

Explanation: in the first example, you have anonymous structure, inside which `struct list` is forward declared. So when compiler sees typedef on the next line it finds a name collision, because typedef is not the same as struct declaration in C++.

Comment: Not quite; in `list* next;` "list" is undeclared.  (C++ lets you refer to "struct list" as "list"; C doesn't.)  You want either `struct list { item_type item; struct list *next; };` (and then refer to the type as "struct list") or `typedef struct list { item_type item; struct list *next; } list;`.

Comment: @Keith -- `list* next;` is declared (compiler would have failed otherwise); inside class body all names (not only class name) are visible. What you probably wanted to say is that `list` is incomplete at that point, which is fine, it doesn't prevent compiler to take a pointer on incomplete type.

Comment: In C++, the declaration of `struct list`, even as an incomplete type, does let you refer to the type as `list`.  In C, it doesn't -- which is why C code commonly uses typedefs for struct types.  (My own preference is to omit the typedef and just refer to the type as `struct list`.)

Answer (score 2):

Since what you're doing is really defining a `struct` and then creating an alias with the `typedef` I think it's more readable to do this in the C case:

```
typedef struct list_ {
    item_type item;
    struct list_* next;
} list;
```

Comment: Why do you use different identifiers for the tag (list_) and the typedef name (list)?  Since struct tags are in a different namespace (in the C sense of the term), it's perfectly legal to write `typedef struct list { ... } list;`; then "struct list" and "list" are two different names for the same type.

Comment: @Keith you're right, I guess I just prefer this style because it gives the impression that the user shouldn't make use of `struct list_`, but should go through the `typedef`, mainly for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

typedef int item_type;

struct list{
    item_type item;
    list* next;
};

void insert_list(list **l, item_type x){ 
    list *p; 
    p = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = x;
    p->next = *l; 
    *l = p;
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `malloc`? This is supposed to be C++ NOT C!

Answer (score 0):

What C only warns against, C++ is likely to consider an error.

It's a programming cultural thing.  C was very forgiving in not enforcing it's typing system.  C++ is still quite forgiving, but you're doing something in C that even C++ won't forgive.

When you malloc that block of memory, cast it to a pointer to a list.  That will covert the address (pointer) to a pointer of the right type.

Without that cast, you could have malloc'd the size of anything, and there's no telling if it was meant to be referenced by a list pointer or some other pointer.

Comment: In C, casting the result of `malloc()` is more likely to create or conceal errors than to solve them.  Just assign the result to your pointer object; the implicit conversion from void* to any pointer-to-object type will take care of the rest.  Use `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` to ensure that all the sizes and types are consistent and correct.  (This is specific to C; for C++, you probably shouldn't be using `malloc()` anyway.)